# Angular 6 [routerLink] won't accept dynamic Auxiliary route

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular6

So I've been trying to make a reusable auxiliary routing component for my application, and have had success updating the routerLink when using dynamic data for a standard route.

```
data = [ {name: 'x', route:'/hello'/} ];

<a *ngFor="let x of data" [routerLink]="x.route"> {{x.name}} </a>
```

So that works fine as does using the auxiliary route without dynamic data.

```
[routerLink]="[ { outlets: { 'admin':['admin']}}]
```

When I try placing  `[{ outlets: { 'admin':['admin']}}]` into the data structure to populate the `[routerLink]="x.route"`

I'm being thrown this error.

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
 'userAccounts/%5B%20%7B%20outlets:%20%7B%20'admin':%5B'admin'%5D%7D%7D%5D'

Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 
'userAccounts/%5B%20%7B%20outlets:%20%7B%20'admin':%5B'admin'%5D%7D%7D%5D'
    at ...
```

A bit perplexed by this so any help would be appreciated.

Edit - I've also tried

```
/(admin:admin) & /parentElement/(admin:admin)
```

Comment: How are you placing `[{ outlets: { 'admin':['admin']}}]` into the data structure? Looks like it's being treated as a string

Comment: route: '[{ outlets: { 'admin':['admin']}}]', should I use ` `  instead?

Comment: No, there should be no quotes at all (except around `admin`), it should just be an array

Comment: Ahh I suppose thinking about it that makes total sense now, that fixed it I appreciate the help I can crack on with the rest now :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jojpjg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I have same problem in my project.. but in stackblitz it works perfectly.. I have tried more dynamic options here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxz6mx?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts So I need to find the difference.